# How to move overall project settings from database to code?

Tags: c#, sql-server, data-manipulation

I need to move two database tables data into code. These tables consist of some data settings (30 and 1000 lines accordingly). This movement of data is a first step towards bigger refactoring. As a result i would like to get rid of two tables, have this data stored somewhere in code. SQL Server and C# are used.

I can not do:

- use application settings because of it is not one project or even one solution to use this data
- use another database (no-SQL)

The problems i am facing at the moment are:

- what tool to use to move data from DB to code (moving 1000 lines manually scares me)
- no idea how to store these settings (readonly lists, dictionaries or something)
- where to store these settings to have access from any project

Thank you for your time and ideas.

EDIT: I need to move data from database because this data is static that means that it will not be changed much in future. This data also consists of UI settings that is not a good idea to store it in DB. From the other hand we need to reduce the number of database calls. And this data is a good candidate to be moved out of the database.

Comment: 1. create custom tools to automate 2. why use settings?

Comment: I would probably make a custom tool to read all the data and export it to a xml/json file. Then put that file in a shared path so all the projects could access it

Comment: Can you share a little more information on why you want to move these settings out of a database?  What are the constraints/benefits driving this effort?  Without context, it is a little hard to make a good recommendation - although @Pikoh makes a good suggestion.

Comment: "this data will not be changed much in the future". Maybe not, but whenever it is, you'll need to re-compile and publish your application(s). "it is not one project or even one solution to use this data" In that case, you need some centralised storage, or else you will end up duplicating this code and have a maintenance overhead. A database is ideal for this. "we need to reduce the number of database calls". Unless your code for this is incredibly bad, just pulling a few settings out will not cause a big performance problem, if you've got DB issues I would trace what is causing the real issue